# Webhook\change notification when User reset\update password

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft365

We are having a Microsoft 365 Tenant with a Global Admin and other end users. We have a requirement that whenever the User\Admin updates his password we need to perform some critical activity.

If we create a change notification subscription for user Object through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks will that send notification whenever the User rest\change the password ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes !

I had the subscription  with the below config :

```
{
    "changeType": "updated",
    "notificationUrl": "<URL>",
    "resource": "users",
    "expirationDateTime": "2021-02-12T11:00:00.0000000Z",
    "clientState": "SecretClientState"
}
```

Trigger to the notification URL occured on the below required events :

- resetting the password (I checked for admin password reset, assuming that the self reset should also work)
- changing the password by the user.

Comment: How do you configure it?

Comment: Hello @BhaskarDabhi, you could use the reference article to configure. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-delivery-webhooks?tabs=http